# wsgi + django returning imports as NoneType

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have an application that works absolutely fine when run as ./manage.py runserver (or even runserver_plus), but when I deploy it to an apache2+wsgi instance, it breaks. The first model it tries to import (UserProfile) it appears to have imported the requested modules as NoneType.

So, a model like this (this is not exact code, it's not something I can paste onto a public site right now):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from BlogEngine.categorisation.models import Category

from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

import logging

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

    category    = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True, related_name="category")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Profile for %s" % user.username

    def update_categories(self):
        """Updates the categories list"""

        pull_more = self.category_selection_max - self.category.count()

        if pull_more == 0:
            return self.category_selection

        logging.debug("Drawing %s categories" % draw)

        categories = Category.objects.filter(
            is_live=True
        ).order_by("?")[:pull_more]

        ## More code under here ##
```

Returns:

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'debug'

at the line logging.debug("Drawing %s categories" % draw)

Commenting that out results in getting

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'objects'

at the line below it instead, and so on. Everything's definitely being imported, and it works fine under the dev server.

My WSGI file is:

```
import sys
import site
import os

vepath = '/home/aquarion/newsite/django/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages'

#prev_sys_path = list(sys.path)
## add the site-packages of our virtualenv as a site dir
site.addsitedir(vepath)
## add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/home/aquarion/newsite/django/')

# import from down here to pull in possible virtualenv django install
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'BlogEngine.settings'
application = WSGIHandler()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `sys.modules` contain?

Comment: A dictionary with the keys of all the modules I've tried to import, plus their dependencies, and the value of "None" for most of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Not sure if it's a bug in something, but it ended up being an issue with using django's user profile stuff and having Admin model information in the models.py file. Once I moved all that into its own admin.py file, everything worked.

Still not sure what causes it exactly, but that's the solution.

(Solution reached via http://osdir.com/ml/DjangoUsers/2009-07/msg00090.html and its reply)

Comment: Likely you triggered some import ordering dependency or import loop. Such an issue may not be notice on development server because it preloads a lot of Django stuff before the server starts. The production WSGI interface and startup mechanism provided by Django doesn't and uses lazy loading. Seems to bite a reasonable number of people. See 'http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html'.